# How to say "next month 15th" in PHP's DateTime?

Tags: php, datetime

### What I want to do:

Getting a certain day from a certain month directly via the DateTime methods (no mktime stunts :)), like

```
$day = new DateTime('15th of next month');
```

but it's not possible to set a fixed day by it's number.
Can anybody help ?

EDIT: I've changed the DateTime from this month to next month to make the problem more clear.

Comment: have you checked ? http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.setdate.php

Comment: Yes, but I don't know the year and month, just the day, so I cannot use setdate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `DateTime::createFromFormat()`. If you only pass the `day` value, it'll default to the current month and year.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d', '15');

echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); // 2018-10-15
```

Edit for the new question requirements:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d', 15)->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));

echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); // 2018-11-15
```

Comment: Thanks, but the point it to use the relative wordinds that allow "next month" etc.

Comment: Ah, you didn't say that ;)

Comment: @Sliq - it's inclear, are you just trying to get the 15th of every month?

Comment: Thanks, `createFromFormat('d', 15)` actually did the thing :) I'd like to add (for people reading this) that `->add(new DateInterval('P1M'))` is broken in PHP and will sometimes skip a month (!), plz see http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.modify.php#119082

Comment: @Sliq - it's not broken per-se. If you start with the date `31-01-2018` and add `30` or `31` days, it'll take you into March. What should it do instead? Fortunately for your case, every month has 15 days, so adding a month should have no unexpected results.